# Eclipse, Checkstyle and spaces in a java doc comment

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I have installed the [Checkstyle](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/checkstyle-plug?mpc=true&mpc_state=) plugin for Eclipse. When i habe writen now a doc comment for a method and there is an empty line line between my acutal comment and the parameter list, like this:

```
/**
 * A comment.
 *
 * @param param A param.
 */
void aMethod(String param) {
    // some code
}
```

Checkstyle now complaints that there is an trailing space. And, although i didn't put a space at that postition there is an extra space...

```
..../**
.....*.A.comment\.
.....*.
.....*.@param.param.A.param\.
.....*/
```

It looks to me that Eclipse is adding this extra space to the docblock. How can i turn that off or configure the checkstyle plugin to ignore this extra space in a docblock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am supposing that you have already tried going to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments` and ensuring that there is no trailing space for Constructors and so on.

I have had a lot of success with the Eclipse Plugin [AnyEdit Tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/). There is an option to removing trailing whitespace and another to Convert tabs to space, both of which will make Checkstyle much happier.

Comment: AnyEdit is awesome. Thank you, I have been having real trouble detecting all those trailing spaces.